Keymaps within an add on's preference panel
I am learning to build a simple add on executed by shortcut keys. I have the add on working with a keymap that I defined upon registering. The user can change this keymap from Preferences > Keymap and then searching for the add on by name. But I would like to allow the user to change that keymap from within the add on's preference panel directly.

I have a lot of add ons that do this (like Cablerator, below). It appears to be drawing the exact same UI from the Keymap preferences, but I can't seem to find resources or examples of how this is done.

Does the API expose some of this easily that I can use? How are folks doing this?
